# Ensure `NonlinearModelFit` goes to $1$

Tags: fitting

```
data = {0, 0, 0.0167, 0.0351, 0.0725, 0.1445, 0.2217, 0.313, 0.4042, 0.4961, 0.5782, 0.6544, 0.7164, 0.7717, 0.8141, 0.8522, 0.8803, 0.9055};
nlm = NonlinearModelFit[data, a + b CDF[LogNormalDistribution[c, d], t], {a, b, c, d}, t];
Show[Plot[{nlm[t], 1}, {t, 1, Floor[2 Length@data]}, 
PlotRange -> All], ListPlot[data]]
```

How do I add constraints in order to ensure `NonlinearModelFit` goes to $1$, and gives best fit, given this requirement?

**Update**

Silly mistake here, corrected with

```
nlm = NonlinearModelFit[data, 
CDF[LogNormalDistribution[a, b], t], {a, b}, t];
Show[Plot[{nlm[t], 1}, {t, 1, Floor[2 Length@data]}, 
PlotRange -> All], ListPlot[data]]
```

[image]

Comment: In addition you have   to ensure `NonlinearModelFit` goes to zero for `t->-Infinity`?

Comment: @UlrichNeumann Ideally, yes

Comment: Your $a$ and $b$ coefficients are giving it the freedom to not start at zero and go to 1. If you delete them, you get the behavior you want. Are they absolutely required? Edit: ahh, you caught it.

Comment: @MikeY yes, just realised! Sorry!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using your data you apply the constraints by making a list. The first element is the model and subsequent elements are constraints.

```
nlm2 = NonlinearModelFit[
   data,
   {
    a + b CDF[NormalDistribution[c, d], t],
    a + b CDF[NormalDistribution[c, d], ∞] == 1,
    a + b CDF[NormalDistribution[c, d], 0] == 0
    },
   {a, b, c, d},
   t
   ];
```

and then

```
Show[
 ListPlot[data,
  PlotRange -> {Automatic, {0, 1}},
  PlotStyle -> Red
  ],
 Plot[nlm2[t],
  {t, 1, Floor[1.5 Length@data]},
  PlotRange -> {0, 1},
  PlotStyle -> Black
  ]
 ]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: many thanks, but have just realised my mistake!

Comment: Clearly better. Good job.